# '{' is not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new on Python and following the Google Developers tutorial. I got an error -->  ***'{' is not recognized as internal or external command*** when running 'python code.py .' with the code below. I believe my PATH variable is set correctly for python as I can run other python codes without problem. Can anybody give me some suggestions?

```
import os
import sys
import commands

def List(dir):
    cmd = 'dir' + dir
    print 'about to do this:', cmd
    (status, output) = commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)
    if status:
        sys.stderr.write('there was an error:'+ output)
        sys.exit(1)
    print output

def main():
    List(sys.argv[1])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What is the argument when you run the command, and what is the exact output?

Comment: `python ./script.py .` cannot reproduce

Comment: I run the command like eg. python code.py . and the exact output is '{' is not recognized as internal or external command. I was just running the code in Jupyter and it seems the error is related to commands.getstatusoutput(cmd) line.
`
C:\Anaconda2\lib\commands.py in getstatusoutput(cmd)
     57     """Return (status, output) of executing cmd in a shell."""
     58     import os
---> 59     pipe = os.popen('{ ' + cmd + '; } 2>&1', 'r')
     60     text = pipe.read()
     61     sts = pipe.close()

TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'builtin_function_or_method' objects`

Comment: @chepner , pls see above

Comment: What is `commands`? That error message indicates an incomplete command being passed to `os.popen` (probably should be `os.popen('{ ' + cmd + '; } 2>&1', 'r')`).

Comment: `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'builtin_function_or_method' objects` is a different error. Please edit your question and add the relevant details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *commands* module doesn't work on Windows – it's Unix-only. Additionally, it's deprecated since version 2.6, and it has been removed in Python 3, so you should use the subprocess module instead. Replace these lines:

```
import commands
(status, output) = commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)
```

With something like this:

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output(['dir', dir])
```

Answer (score 0):

Also following the Google Python course..
My commands.getstatusoutput() replacement looks like this:

```
import subprocess
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(['dir', dir])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print "Command error: " + e.output
    print "Command output: " + output
    sys.exit(e.returncode)
```